# Can't add page to Android Wear notification without the card background

Tags: android, wear-os

It's quite possible Android Wear just doesn't support this but there seems there should be some workaround. I want to add a custom second page to a notification, but I don't want it to have the white card background.

Here's how I create my notifications:

```
Intent secondPageIntent = new Intent(this, SecondPageActivity.class);
PendingIntent secondPagePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, secondPageIntent, 0);


Notification secondPageNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                                        .setDisplayIntent(secondPagePendingIntent)
                                        .setHintShowBackgroundOnly(true)
                        )
                        .build();

Intent firstPageIntent = new Intent(this, FirstPageActivity.class);
PendingIntent firstPagePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, firstPageIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
                                        .setDisplayIntent(firstPagePendingIntent)
                                        .setBackground(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background))
                                        .addPage(secondPageNotification)
                        );


NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
                notificationManager.notify(curNotificationId++, builder.build());
```

I've tried:

1. Setting setHintShowBackgroundOnly which doesn't do anything
2. From within SecondPageActivity, try to grab parentActivity and set it's alpha to 0. Doesn't work, parentActivity is null.
3. Calling setCustomContentHeight(0) doesn't remove the card, it just gets skinny
4. I tried not using a second page but instead launching an activity when the user swipes but it doesn't look good

I really have no idea what to try next. I'm an experienced engineer but pretty new to Android. Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen my answer below? Can you give me any feedback if it works for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the white card you have to set

```
setCustomSizePreset(WearableExtender.SIZE_FULL_SCREEN)
```

So instead of something like that:
[image: custom content with card decoration]

your custom content will appear on entire screen (without the card decoration).
[image: custom content without card decoration]

Please notice that the background of your custom activity is defined by the style declared in manifest. Unfortunately any theme with transparent background won't work, so the background needs to be opaque:(

This is submitted as an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73900
I really hope that they will allow transparent backgrounds there in future:\

Comment: Thanks that works, although the transparency issue is a problem :/ Hopefully they fix that soon.

Comment: is it possible to have a ViewPager as activity content? Still, nice answer +1 from me

Comment: I doubt it would work properly because of the gesture related restrictions (swiping)